# Invalid multi-line string in terraform

Tags: terraform, grafana

Using regular expressions I am trying to filter unwanted strings from the list in variable:

```
resource "grafana_rule_group" "cw_sqs_rule_group" {
  name             = "SQS queues"
  folder_uid       = grafana_folder.cw_sqs_rule_folder.uid
  interval_seconds = 180
  org_id           = 1
  rule {
    name           = "SQS message is older than 3 minutes""
    for            = "10m"
    condition      = "C"
    no_data_state  = "NoData"
    exec_err_state = "Alerting"
    annotations = {
      "description" = "{{ with $values }} SQS message is: {{ humanizeDuration $values.B.Value }} old {{ end }}"

    }
    labels = {
      "env" = var.env
      "instance" = "SQS queue"
    }
    is_paused = false
    data {
      ref_id     = "A"
      query_type = ""
      relative_time_range {
        from = 1800
        to   = 0
      }
      datasource_uid = grafana_data_source.cloudwatch.uid
      model = jsonencode({
        dimensions = {
          QueueName = [ for queue_name in var.sqs_queues_list : queue_name if length(regexall(".+-dead-letter$", queue_name)) == 0 ]
        }
```

while it kind of works if iterate it over the list in variable it throws an error when I am not iterating:

```
Error: Invalid multi-line string
  On grafana.tf line 1160: Quoted strings may not be split
  over multiple lines. To produce a multi-line string, either use the \n
  escape to represent a newline character or use the "heredoc" multi-line
  template syntax.
```

By saying "kind of" I meant that it was about creating multiple rules for each variable from the list including these filtered for filtered `dimensions`.

variable is list of strings:

```
variable "sqs_queues_list" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = [
    "first-queue",
    "second-queue",
    "third-dead-letter"
  ]
}
```

I've tried it in single line but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration seems to have a syntax error:

```
    name           = "SQS message is older than 3 minutes""
```

Notice that there's an extra quote character `"` at the end of this string literal.

I think this syntax error is causing Terraform's parser to be a bit confused about where your string templates start and end, making it think there's a newline character in one of them. If you fix that syntax error then it will hopefully either work as you intended or produce a more relevant error message that you could ask about in a separate question if it's unclear.